# About non-negative matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

If $W$ is diagonal matrix with each entry $W_{i,i}>0$, $K$ is a
symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix and $K_{i,j}>0$ (actually $K$ is a kernel matrix and calculated from a RBF kernel function), each
element of vector $x$ is larger than 0, can we say that
$(W+K^{-1})^{-1}x$ is a vector with each entry larger than 0?

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking whether $(W+K^{-1})^{-1}$ is a (entrywise) positive matrix. The answer is negative. Counterexample: suppose $W=10\,I_3$,
$$
X=(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\begin{pmatrix}
0.9883 &0.5155 &0.2259\\
0.5828 &0.3340 &0.5798\\
0.4235 &0.4329 &0.7604
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $K$ is the RBF kernel matrix such that $K_{ij}=\exp(-\|x_i-x_j\|_2^2)$. Then
$$
(W+K^{-1})^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
0.0829 &0.0124 &-0.0010\\
0.0124 &0.0728 &0.0136\\
-0.0010 &0.0136 &0.0818
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, when $x=(1,\varepsilon,\varepsilon)^T$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, the third entry of $(W+K^{-1})^{-1}x$ is negative.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your answer $K_0$ has negative entry. In my question, each entry of $K$ is computed from a RBF kernel function, e.g. $K_{i, j} = \exp(-||x_i-x_j||_2^2/\sigma_2)$. $x_i$ and $x_j$ are high-dimensional vectors.

Comment: @user68361 I see. See my new edit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, which helps me a lot.